# Formatting wide output via 'column' (or similar) command(s)

Tags: json, linux, vim, jq, unix-text-processing

This question actually asks the 'inverse' solution as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074839/column-width-parameter-not-working), namely I would like to wrap the long column (column 4) on multiple lines. In effect, the output should look like:

```
cat test.csv | column -s"," -t -c5 

col1 col2  col3  col4                col5
1    2     3     longLineOfText      5
                 ThatIWantTo
                 InspectAndWould
                 LikeToWrap
```

(excuse the u.u.o.c. duplicated over here :) )

---

The solution would *ideally* :

- make use of standard *nix text processing utilities (e.g. `column`, `paste`, `pr` which usually are present on any modern Linux machine nowadays, usually coming from the `core-utils` package);
- avoid `jq` as it is not necessarily present on every (production) system;
- don't overheat the brain: yes... am looking mainly at you `awk` & co. gurus :). "Normal" `awk / perl / sed` is fine.
- as a *special bonus* , a solution using `vim` would be even more welcome (again, no brain smoke please), since that would allow for syntax-coloring as well.

The background: I want to be able to make sense of the output  of `docker history`, so **as a last resort** even some `Go` *Template-magic* would suit,  as would using `jq`.

In extreme cases (if the benefits of ease-of-remembering-and-use outweigh the inconvenience of downloading a new utilty (preferably self-contained / static linked) utility on the server - is ok, or using `json` processing commands (in which case using `python`s json module would be preferred)

Thanks !

**LE:**
**Please keep in mind, that `docker`s output has the columns separated with several *spaces*, which unfortunately confuses most commands :(**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Did you try the `-W` option? E.g. `cat test.csv | column -s"," -t -W4 -c40`

Comment: @romainl: Tried `docker history image | column -t -W4`  with various  options for the separator, but `column`  always gets confused at the separator  which is a sequence of spaces in docker-s output. seems. 
@pmf: Thanks, but it doesn't _cut_ it :) since also by looking at manual page, seems that `-c` option is not specific to a column, but to entire output, isn't it ?

Comment: Several solutions are offered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778612/how-to-wrap-lines-within-columns-in-linux

Comment: @peak: yes, but all use  awk / perl , are complex & hard to remember, are actually more like programs than one-liners, unfortunately

Comment: @cg79 what's wrong with storing those scripts under `~/bin` and calling them? You don't need to remember them, you only need to give them a short name.